# How to packetize H264 in RTP?

Tags: video, h.264, packet, rtp, wowza

I have H264 stream from my mobile camera. In my Java app I can access the stream frame by frame already encoded with H264.
I need to stream it to Wowza media server. Since wowza understands only RTP/RTSP streams can I just add RTP header infront of each frame data and stream it to wowza?

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 10):

It is not as simple as just adding a header.

- RTP packetization will require you to do fragmentation on the H.264 bitstream according to [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)
- If Wowza requires support for RTSP, you have to implement RTSP server and implement RTSP protocol to manage your RTP stream

You might want to check out VLC if it can acquire video from your camera directly or through your application, and re-expose it with RTSP/RTP protocol. If you find a suitable option, it might appear to be easier to complete the streaming sequence this way.